# Is javascript date object compatible to python datetime object

Tags: javascript, python, django

For example in python, a date can be something like: 2020-06-19T11:32:16.548109Z,
is there a way that i can use to convert this to a javascript Date object?

Comment: This is an ISO 8601 format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: JS has millisecond precision whereas python has microsecond precision, you may need to strip the last three digits to round to the nearest thousandths? But this does not seem to matter. The `Date` constructor can read ISO format e.g. `new Date('2020-06-19T11:32:16.548109Z')`

Comment: thank you soo much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your date from python is serialized into an [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) date format, then you can simply pass the string into the `Date` constructor in JavaScript. The precision of the decimal fraction is non-standard, as it is up the the language to decide that.

```js
// 2020-06-19T11:32:16.548Z
new Date('2020-06-19T11:32:16.548109Z').toISOString()
```

```js
// Fri, 19 Jun 2020 11:32:16 GMT
new Date('2020-06-19T11:32:16.548109Z').toUTCString()
```

---

**Note:** In Python, the precision of timestamp epochs are to the nearest microsecond. JavaScript will just ignore those when deserializing, because it uses millisecond epochs.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles):

> *If necessary for a particular application, the standard supports the addition of a decimal fraction to the smallest time value in the representation.*

Check this article out, as it explains how different languages handle ISO 8601:

> ***[ISO 8601 and Nanosecond Precision Across Languages](https://nbsoftsolutions.com/blog/iso-8601-and-nanosecond-precision-across-languages)***